# `IIncrementalGenerator` generators locally but not in Github Action

Tags: .net-core, sourcegenerators

I'm working on a source generator that currently works fine on four different machines (two Windows, two Linux), but when my Github Action is building the project, the generator fails with a `TypeInitializationException`.

I've executed the exact same commands on all four machines and the complete pipeline works locally. I even tweaked my pipeline to attach a `msbuild.binlog` but unfortunately I'm not skilled enough to properly analyze it.

The repo is this one: [FastLogr](https://github.com/MichaelHochriegl/FastLogr/tree/test/4-add-integration-tests)

The pipeline fails when executing `dotnet build -c Release --no-restore --force /bl` with this output:

```
Run dotnet build -c Release --no-restore --force /bl
MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET
  FastLogr.Attributes -> /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/src/FastLogr.Attributes/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/FastLogr.Attributes.dll
  FastLogr.Generator -> /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/src/FastLogr.Generator/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/FastLogr.Generator.dll
CSC : warning CS8784: Generator 'FastLogrGenerator' failed to initialize. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'TypeInitializationException' with message 'The type initializer for 'FastLogr.Generator.FastLogrGenerator' threw an exception.' [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService.csproj]
Error: /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/Worker.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SourceGenPlayground' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService.csproj]
  FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Verify -> /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Verify/bin/Release/net7.0/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Verify.dll
CSC : warning CS8784: Generator 'FastLogrGenerator' failed to initialize. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'TypeInitializationException' with message 'The type initializer for 'FastLogr.Generator.FastLogrGenerator' threw an exception.' [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration.csproj]
Error: /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/TestCode/PrimitiveTypesTests.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SourceGenPlayground' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration.csproj]

Build FAILED.

CSC : warning CS8784: Generator 'FastLogrGenerator' failed to initialize. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'TypeInitializationException' with message 'The type initializer for 'FastLogr.Generator.FastLogrGenerator' threw an exception.' [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService.csproj]
CSC : warning CS8784: Generator 'FastLogrGenerator' failed to initialize. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'TypeInitializationException' with message 'The type initializer for 'FastLogr.Generator.FastLogrGenerator' threw an exception.' [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration.csproj]
Error: /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/Worker.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SourceGenPlayground' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/example/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService/FastLogr.Example.WorkerService.csproj]
Error: /home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/TestCode/PrimitiveTypesTests.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SourceGenPlayground' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/runner/work/FastLogr/FastLogr/test/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration/FastLogr.Generator.Tests.Integration.csproj]
    2 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:10.20
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to reproduce the issue on 4 different machines, but on there it works.

My machines are running the following dotnet sdks:

1. 7.0.109 (Fedora linux machine)
2. 7.0.109 (Fedora linux machine)
3. 7.0.304 (Windows 10 machine)
4. 7.0.306 (Windows 11 machine)

I've tried using the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset` nuget with version `4.6.0` to supply every machine with the same compiler version, but again, all machines run fine by using this, GH action fails with the same error.

I tried to analyze the `msbuild.binlog` that I attached to every GH action run, but I didn't find anything that points me in the direction to solve this, but than again I'm not that skilled with analyzing the `binlog`.